# What's the numerator and the denominator of a fraction called?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, rational-numbers

[image]

Just a quick question,  is it right to call the numerator and the denominator of a fraction by "terms"?
I don't think that "terms" is the right word here, but i don't know any alternatives. Can any one help me with this?!
What are the right word here to use instead of "Terms"?

Comment: Integers? What are you going for? Technically the top and bottom are terms,  so you can use the word term is you want.

Comment: Alternatively call them number in this case.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen: I think "terms" was meant by Mohaimn Draz for its mathematical (not linguistic) use, such as the terms of a polynomial or the terms appearing in an equation. Off-hand, I can't think of a word/phrase that means "numerator" or "denominator" that does not specifically designate one of them, in the sense that "one-sided" (or "unilateral") means "left" or "right" (as in limit at a point of a function). So I agree with Mohaimn Draz --- I don't think "terms" is the correct word to use in this problem.

Comment: What about "members" ?

Answer (score 3):

The numerator and the denominator are the "parts" of a fraction.

It comes from the terminology of simple fractions. The fraction $\dfrac{2}{3}$ is two parts out of three parts.

Comment: "Parts" sounds better to me than anything I've seen or thought of thus far. By the way, sometime in the mid 1990s I spent the night in a hotel where your university is, and spent several hours the next day in your university's library before continuing my trip. Yes, I know it's small, but it had a journal I wanted some papers from and I also wanted to browse the shelves to see if anything of interest I didn't know about was there. I don't remember the journal, but I do remember the library photocopy machine produced about the worst copies I've ever made! I *think* this was June 1994.